# Conditionally adding one more condition to a LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have something like this:

```
public Assignments GetAssignmentsForProider(string provider_k, string recordType)
{
    if (recordType == "A")
    {
       var query = from ea in this.Context.Assignments
            where ea.Provider_K == provider_k
                  && ea.Active == true
                  && ea.RecordType == "A"
            select ea;
        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else if (recordType == "E")
    {
       var query = from ea in this.Context.Assignments
            where ea.Provider_K == provider_k
                  && ea.RecordType == "E"
            select ea;
        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Two problems:

1. It doesn't compile! because it needs a default return statement too and I am not sure what to return really but in my program it will never happen that none of those if conditions happen. I am always in the first one or second one.
2. Really all they are different in is in first one we check for `Active == true` and in second one we don't. So is there a better way of writing this too?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the record type is neither "E" nor "A"? You may say it's impossible, but your code doesn't say that... which is why the compiler's complaining. You could potentially drop the "if" from the else/if, or you could add an exception at the end of the method.

Comment: If you are always in 1 of the 2 if-statements as you claim, then you can make the second just an else without an if

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet I think it should return empty row because in my program I want to check and say if(result != null)

Comment: @DevWannaBe: Right, so that's what you should make your code do. Not that null isn't the same as an empty result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public Assignments GetAssignmentsForProider(string provider_k, string recordType)
{
    var query = from ea in this.Context.Assignments
        where ea.Provider_K == provider_k
                && ea.RecordType == recordType
                && (recordType == "E" ? true : ea.Active)
            select ea;
        return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This should satisfy your need.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably write it like this:

```
public Assignments GetAssignmentsForProider(string provider_k, string recordType)
{
    var query = from ea in this.Context.Assignments
                where ea.Provider_K == provider_k &&
                      ea.RecordType == recordType
                select ea;

    if (recordType == "A")
        return query.Where(ea => ea.Active).FirstOrDefault();
    else if (recordType == "E")
        return query.FirstOrDefault();

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to chain your conditions ...

```
public Assignments GetAssignmentsForProider(string provider_k, string recordType)
{
    var query = from ea in this.Context.Assignments
                where ea.Provider_K == provider_k
                select ea;

    if (recordType == "A")
    {
       query = from q in query
               where q.Active == true
                  && q.RecordType == "A"
               select q;
    }
    else if (recordType == "E")
    {
       query = from q in query
               where q.RecordType == "E"
               select q;    
    }

    return query;
}
```

But Bjarke Søgaard has the better method for filtering on record type, because your criteria parameter directly matches on the query data ... so you could just use it directly.